# Five girls stand in a line. How many possible permutations are there in which Anya is at the left of the line or Elena is on the right, or both?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Five girls, Anya, Beth, Carol, Dasha and Elena, stand in a line. How many possible permutations are there in which Anya is at the left of the line or Elena is on the right, or both?

If we want Anya to be at the left she must occupy the first or the second place in the line (starting from the left). That would be 24 possibilities each place, 24+24=48

The same thing applies to Elena as she should be in either one of the two places at the right side, so there are 24+24=48 possibilities for her too

If we want Anya to be at the left and Elena to be at the right at the same time, we find that there are 4 combinations:
A _ _ E _,
A _ _ _ E,
_ A _ E _,
_ A _ _ E,

And each one represents 6 possibilities, therefore 6x4=24

Adding all the results 48+48=96, and subtracting the 24 that are already included there, the answer would be 72 but the book says 42

Comment: See here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750337/combinatorics-removing-double-counted-cases

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorics - Removing Double Counted Cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750337/combinatorics-removing-double-counted-cases)

Comment: The way I read the question, Anya must be in the leftmost position of the line, Elena must be in the rightmost of the line, or both of those conditions must hold.  Please see my answers to the linked question.

Comment: It may be that Anya and Dasha and identical twins and do not know themselves who is who. Then the answer is different.

Answer (score 0):

Why can Anya be in the second position if we want her to be at the left?  If we want her on the left, she has to be in the first position.  There are then $4!=24$ orders possible.  As you say, symmetry says that the number with Elena on the right is the same.  We then deduct the ones with both, because we have counted them twice.  That is $3!=6$, and $2\cdot 24-6=42$.  This is an English question, not a math one.  You are reading "at the left" as being in the left half (not including the center).  I am claiming that it means being at the left end.

Comment: "Why can Anya be in the second position if we want her to be at the left?" Because Anya is very stubborn. And if you want her to do what she does not want, then you should shut up.

Comment: @Ross-Milikan thank you, English is not my first language so I mixed things up, I really appreciate your answer! :D